# setting the class path on linux to run java program

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run this command on linux... compilation is successfull but while running it gives error.
Executing this command:

```
java -cp .:/smash/same/hope/ant-launcher-1.6.1.jar src.vp
```

output

```
Setting the value for property-debug
Fusion Repository/asd/file/repo
Logs Directory
Running validations
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/Project
    at src.vp.call(vp.java:114)
    at src.vp.main(vp.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Project
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
    ... 2 more
```

Can some one help me to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included the `ant-launcher` jar file, but that doesn't contain the whole of ant, I'm sure. Look for the ant jar file that includes the `Project` class. (I'd expect it to be ant-1.6.1.jar based on the other file you've specified.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I had added it during compilation.... but forgot while running....Thanks!